# Handwriting LALR(1) parser, navigating the table

Tags: c++, parsing, interpreter

for educational purposes (after the formal languages course) i and a friend wanted to write a simplified c-like interpreter manually (not using bison & friends).

We have almost everything done: the tokenizer and the ast classes are all already implemented, and we made the LALR(1) parsing table for our grammar and compared it with the parsing table generated by [this website](http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html) just to double check correctness.

But now we're kind of lost; how to actually write code that efficiently navigates the LALR table allocating ast classes on reduce?
Is there an efficient or "standard" way to implement the lalr table navigation?
Looking online we keep finding only questions and examples about how to build the table but literally nothing about how to navigate it.

Comment: the shfit/reduce operations are pretty much self explanatory. WHen shifting you take data from input to parsing stack and when reducing you remove data from stack (disclaimer: these are memories from my compiler course)

Comment: i know what do shift and reduce mean, what i don't know is how to actually navigate the table @bartop; how to efficiently manage the stack, taking next token, looking in the table; it's more a question about how to structure the code.

Comment: these are pretty vague questions. I think you should consider making them more specific, because what you are asking for is wide area of opinion based answers

Comment: What do you mean by "navigate"? The table is conceptually a simple two-dimensional array, so you just index it with the current state and lookahead token number. Then you do whatever is indicated: shift the token, perform the reduce action, signal an error. Repeat until done. Are you asking about table compression? Or what?